# Update column values based on parts of another 2 columns values

Tags: mysql, wordpress, string-concatenation

I'm trying to migrate a database from a custom CMS to WordPress. Working through phpMyAdmin in MySQL, I need to generate a new column based on the values of another two pre-existing columns:

```
+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| id               | post_date           | guid               |
+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| WW955q4ifda1j971 | 2005-08-02 16:51:48 |                    |
| WW955q4m1dlklhx1 | 2005-08-02 16:59:36 |                    |
| WW955q4n3pko4dsw | 2005-08-02 17:01:54 |                    |
+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

This new column would be called `guid` and should have the following value structure: `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2005/08/WW955q4ifda1j971.jpg`

It needs to be constructed using parts of the `post_date` value and the whole `id`, like so: `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/[post_date-year]/[post_date-month]/[id].jpg`

I know almost nothing about MySQL, that's why I usually work through phpMyAdmin, and I really need your help.

Hope this wasn't too confusing :P Thanks in advance, guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the update query you need: (substitute table for your table name)

```
UPDATE table
SET guid = CONCAT(
    "http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/",
    YEAR(post_date),"/",
    DATE_FORMAT(post_date, "%m"),"/",
    id,".jpg"
);
```

Edit: this assumes that the post_date column has a DATETIME data type. If it is a VARCHAR, instead of just `YEAR(post_date)` and `DATE_FORMAT(post_date, "%m")`, you will have to use `YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(post_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"))` and `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(post_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%), "%m")`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I got this error:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%m),"/",
    id,".jpg"
)' at line 5`

Comment: Yes! My bad, I did not put quotes around the `%m` format for the month. I have fixed it, and tested it.

Comment: Now it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, Array :)